# Как привести object к типу класса

Tags: c#, классы, объекты

Есть класс

```
class FtpFile
{
    private string file;

    public string File
    {
        get { return file; }
        set { file = value; }
    }
}
```

В цикле создаю новые объекты класса FtpFile и добавляю их в List

```
var listFtpFile = new List<FtpFile>();

FtpFile ftpFile;

for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
    ftpFile = new FtpFile();
    ftpFile.File = i.ToString();
    listFtpFile.Add(ftpFile);
}



for (int k = 0; k < listFtpFile.Count; k++)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(() => check(listFtpFile[k]));
    thread.Start();

}

public void check(obj lis) // Вот здесь у меня он ругается.
{
    var data = (FtpFile)lis.File; // вот здесь он выдает error. 
              // хотя в отладчике в lis есть данные
}
```

В методе check я хочу привести тип Object к FtpFile, но почему то не получается.

> Error CS0051  Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'FtpFile' is less accessible than method 'Form1.check(FtpFile)'`

Comment: `public void check(obj lis) // Вот здесь у меня он ругается.` тут все нормально?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void check(object lis) // Вот здесь у меня он ругается.
{
    FtpFile ftpFile = lis as FtpFile;
    if (null != lis)
    {
         var data = ftpFile.File; 
    } 
}
```

Еще можно так, если уверены что `lis` является `FtpFile`

```
var d = ((FtpFile)lis).File;
```

Comment: Спасибо за адекватность)

Comment: @Radzhab, обновил ответ. Что бы ексепшинов не было.

Answer (score 3):

Присвойте классу FtpFile соответствующий уровень доступа. По всей видимости это public

Comment: а какой поставить? у меня он internal

Comment: русским же языком написано: поставьте public